# Get % of how much of a javascript file is commented out

Tags: regular-expression, search, javascript

I'm wanting to check if files are more than 50% commented out with javascript style commenting of `//`. My idea is to count the number of lines in the file and then count the number of `//` and do some simple math.

It get's tricky if someone uses multiline comments though `/* ... */`

What's a better way to go about this?

Comment: 1. Pack JS into file1. 2. Check file size. 3. Remove comments and save into file2. 4. Check file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this shell script works for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "You have to specify a file. Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi 

if [ ! -r $1 ]; then
    echo "File '$1' doesn't exist or is not readable. Exiting..."
    exit
fi

# count every line
lines=$(wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}')
echo "$lines total lines."

# count '//' comments
commentType1=$(sed -ne '/^[[:space:]]*\/\//p' $1 | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
echo "$commentType1 lines contain '//' comments."

# count single line block comments
commentType2=$(sed -ne '/^[[:space:]]*\/\*.*\*\/[[:space:]]*/p' $1 | wc -l)
echo "$commentType2 single line block comments"

# write code into temporary file because we need to tamper with the code
tmpFile=/tmp/$(date +%s%N)
cp $1 $tmpFile

# remove single line block comments
sed -ie '/^[[:space:]]*\/\*.*\*\/[[:space:]]*/d' $tmpFile

# count multiline block comments
commentType3=$(sed -ne ':start /^[[:space:]]*\/\*/!{n;bstart};p; :a n;/\*\//!{p;ba}; p' $tmpFile | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
echo "$commentType3 of lines belong to block comments."

percent=$(echo "scale=2;($commentType1 + $commentType2 + $commentType3) / $lines * 100" | bc -l)
echo "$percent% of lines are comments"
```

Comment: this seems to be really really close. I'm getting 77% for `commentType2` on a file that doesn't have a single use of multiline comments. [Here is a copy of the file text](http://codepad.org/xslmcobp) - I'd like to be able to solve this myself but I'm not so good with bash commands. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I updated the script. I didn't consider you can write single line block comments...

Comment: I think this is the one. Thanks for your time and consideration in helping my with this question. Cheers!